# How can I use ActionMailer correctly when I want to use BCC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I've spent time for research, and this is what I could think of.
But, I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with this part `@users_emails += user.email`

Can anyone fix my code to make it work?

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def send_all_at_once

    @notification_users = User.where("users.country_id=?", 36)

    @notification_users.each do |user|
        @users_emails += user.email
    end

    @subject = "Test subject"
    @body = "Test body"

    CallMailer.call_email(@users_emails, @subject, @body).deliver

end
```

**app/mailers/call_mailer.rb**

```
class CallMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    default :from => "dont-reply@example.com"

    def call_email(@users_emails, @subject, @body)
        mail(:to => "admin@example.com",
            :bcc => @users_emails,
            :subject => @subject,
            :body => @body) do |format|
            format.html
            format.text
        end
    end 

end
```

**views/call_mailer/call_email.html.erb**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            You received a message.
        </p>
        <p>
            Subject: <%= raw @subject %>
        </p>
        <blockquote>
            <p>
                <%= simple_format(@body) %> 
            </p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>
            From: <%= link_to root_url,root_url %>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you'd pass your bcc'ed email addresses as an array:

```
mail(:to => "admin@example.com",
    :bcc => ['first@email.com', 'second@email.com', 'third@email.com'],
    :subject => @subject,
    :body => @body)
```

**However**, since `@user_emails` is already an array of emails, you should forgo the enclosing brackets and pass the instance variable directly:

```
mail(:to => "admin@example.com",
    :bcc => @users_emails,
    :subject => @subject,
    :body => @body)
```

The following depicts the correct syntax for creating an array of user emails:

```
@notification_users.each do |user|
    @users_emails << user.email
end
```

UPDATE:

As commenter [mbratch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/mbratch) astutely points out, the shovel operator in the above example can be substituted by the plus-equals (`+=`) operator in the following manner:

```
@user_emails = []
@notification_users.each do |user|
    @users_emails += [user.email]
end
```

**UPDATE 2:**

You can bypass the controller loop altogether by mapping user emails directly within your invocation of the `mail` function:

```
mail(:to => "admin@example.com",
    :bcc => User.where("users.country_id=?", 36).map(&:email),
    :subject => @subject,
    :body => @body)
```

Comment: Thanks for a comment! How can I make it array using `@notification_users.each do |user|` and `user.email`?

Comment: Thanks very much:) Everything else looks fine to you?

Comment: You may need to try passing `@users_emails` both with _and_ without enclosing brackets. Since `@users_emails` is already an array, it may be unnecessary to enclose it within an array as you would when passing individual emails, e.g., `['first@email.com', 'second@email.com']`.

Comment: One could, in theory, do `@user_emails += [user.email]` as well.

Comment: @zeantsoi I tried the one before update. Indeed it delivers email but only to `admin@example.com`:( @users_emails didn't receive any email

Comment: I'm using rails3.2.11

Comment: Since `@users_emails` is an array, did you try it without enclosing brackets? Docs for 3.2.1 here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionMailer/Base

Comment: what do you mean by saying without enclosing brackets? sorry for my poor knowledge:(

Comment: `@users_emails += [user.email]` returns the error `undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Use then `<<` shovel method, then. Or check out the second update for an alternative way of passing an array of emails __without__ needing to construct the emails array in your controller action.

Comment: I don't want to use 2nd update. Because `CallMailer.call_email()` will be used in everywhere. This is so weird. even I switched it back to the 1st one it still returns the same error:(

Comment: your 1st suggestion worked fine except BCC didn't work. and I tried your 2nd suggestion, and it started this saying this error `undefined method ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass` I never met this error before

Comment: Thanks! let me try and report!

Comment: @zeantsoi It seems bcc is not working!!!! I did put two of my existing email addresses there. but BCC didn't receive!

Comment: Glad it's working. Just remember that bcc'ing an email that you're also sending the email to directly has been known to cause errors.

Comment: @MKK you need to pre-init your array to `[]` before you can `+=` or `<<` elements into it.